# Error compiling Java/Scala mixed project and Lombok

Tags: java, scala, maven, lombok

I am trying to compile a Maven Java/Scala mixed project that has a Scala class that depends on a Java bean with lombok annotations. I tried adding the lombok jar file to the boot classpath of the Scala compiler as well as the lombok agent, but the compiler still failed to find the generated getters. Is there a way for the Scala compiler to recognize the lombok annotations? If not, what would be a good workaround?

Pease note that I am trying to avoid introducing another maven project just for compiling this bean first as the bean logically belongs to the same project. Also I cannot rewrite the bean in Scala as it is later used in a GWT project.

Thank you,

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you'll not be able to avoid it. Normal Scala/Java integration works like this:

1. Scala goes first, since Java doesn't know anything about Scala.

   1. Scalac parsers Java files and learns about visible elements.
   2. Scalac reads Scala files and generate class files.
2. Java goes last, and reads Java files plus the class files generated by Scala.

The obvious problem is that Scala doesn't know anything about Lombok annotations, so it can't figure out the elements generated by it.

If you don't have any dependency from Java to Scala, you can simply invert the order: let Java go first, and have Scala include the output classfiles of javac on its classpath.

Otherwise, I suppose you'll need to break it up.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. Most of the dependencies go from Java to Scala. So far it is only these kind of beans that create the reverse dependency.

Comment: Lombok developer here:

Do you perhaps know _how_ scala parses java files? ecj? javac? Handrolled parser? I also wonder if this process supports annotation processors at all. If yes, we might be able to do something.

Comment: @rzwitserloot [Handrolled parser](https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/master/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/javac) (it should be surprising -- his work became the basis for the javac starting with JDK 1.3). It does not support annotation processors.

Comment: Thank you all. This clarifies it.