# Why is Lombok in a Scala case class inaccessible in a Java class when using Mixed project?

Tags: scala, lombok

I have a simple Spring boot app with a Scala class...

```
case class TestThing(val name: String ){
  @Getter
  @Setter
  var value = null
  def getMap = {
    val list: List[Item] = List(Item("1", "Foo"), Item("2", "Bar"))
    val map = list.map(item => item.key -> item).toMap
    map("1")
  }
}
```

Now I am trying to access the getter and setter function from a java class like this...

```
@GetMapping("/other")
public String index(){
    TestThing thing = new TestThing("My Name");
    thing.setValue("Test");
    return "Hello World from me "+thing.getMap().value()+"||"+thing.getValue();
}
```

The `thing.getMap()` works fine but I get the following compile error for the getters and setters...

```
  error: cannot find symbol
        return "Hello World from me "+thing.getMap().value()+"||"+thing.getValue();
                                                                       ^
  symbol:   method getValue()
  location: variable thing of type TestThing
```

What am I missing? I found this question ([Error compiling Java/Scala mixed project and Lombok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171631/error-compiling-java-scala-mixed-project-and-lombok)) but it is the reverse and doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lombok doesn't work with Scala. Simple as that. (It is even described why in the issue you linked). The @Getter and @Setter annotations in Scala classes are never processed and the accessors are never generated.

It is also completely unneeded as case classes generate: `toString`, `equals`, `hashcode` getters and setter. If you want to have Java Bean accessors you can use [`@BeanProperty`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/beans/BeanProperty.html) annotation.

```
import scala.beans.BeanProperty

case class TestThing(val name: String ){
  @BeanProperty
  var value: String = null
}
```

```
val test = TestThing("test")
test.getValue // null
test.setValue("test")
test.getValue // "test"
```