# Scala case class extends java class

Tags: java, scala, inheritance, scala-java-interop

I have a normal Java class `BaseModel` as below

```
@AllArgsConstructor
class BaseModel {
   private String id;
}
```

Now I want to extend this in scala case class. Below is giving error:

```
case class Employee(id: String, dept: String) extends BaseModel(id)
```

Error:
too many arguments for constructor BaseModel: ()

EDIT1:
I have also tried with explicit constructor as below:

```
class BaseModel {
   private String id;
   public BaseModel(String id) {
      this.id = id;
   }
}
```

Now with this, it throws an error at compile time `value id needs override modifier`. When I try to add override modifier, it is throwing a compile-time error in the Scala class.

```
case class Employee(override val id: String, dept: String) extends BaseModel(id)
```

The error is for `id`.

Pls help me how can I fix this?

Comment: Your class only has an empty constructor, that annotation generates another one somehow but **Scala** does not understand **Java** annotations.

Comment: Does Scala know about Lombok annotations?

Comment: Updated question with more information.

Comment: @Suman Weird. With your new `BaseModel` `case class Employee(id: String, dept: String) extends BaseModel(id)` should work. Try clean build.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171631/error-compiling-java-scala-mixed-project-and-lombok